# How do I place this file in Ubuntu? (In parallels / OSX)

Tags: 12.04, macosx, lts, parallels

I need to [place a file](https://ripple.com/wiki/Rippled_Server_Setup) in the `/etc/` directory, and I'm unable to copy/paste text into vi.

Since this file is in a Parallels (on OSX) virtual machine, I'm not sure what my options are.

Comment: Do you know how you have your network setup? Is the VM bridged or NAT'd to your local network?

Comment: @Ross Right now it's a shared network... though I can change it if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a simpler way to do this through Parallels (I'm assuming they have some sort of clipboard sharing, similar to VirtualBox), but you can easily copy files over SSH with `scp`.

To copy a file from your Mac OS X home directory to the guest VM's `/etc` directory, you can execute:

```
scp ~/myfile.txt ubuntu@myguestvm:/etc/
```

Where `~` is your user's home directory. `myfile.txt` is the file/object to copy. `ubuntu` is the username on the guest VM (typically defaults to `ubuntu` for servers). `myguestvm` is the hostname (or IP address) of the guest VM . And `/etc/` being the target destination of the `~/myfile.txt`.

You will most likely be prompted for a password, but you can easily setup SSH to be [passwordless](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys).

For more information around `scp` you can execute `man scp` in a terminal.